# How do I simulate the behavior of a standard file field submit with an ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload

## Due Diligence

Just to be clear I have searched for the answer to this question and found these great questions that unfortunately do not help me.

[Submit form including file upload via jQuery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512287/submit-form-including-file-upload-via-jquery-ajax)
[jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form?rq=1)
[jquery using ajax to send data and save in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029703/jquery-using-ajax-to-send-data-and-save-in-php?lq=1)
[jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

## Setup

I have a system for pulling form values and posting them via ajax. A simple snippet may look something like:

```
  // Values
  var url = '/ajax/my/controller'
  var values = myStuff.getFormValues($form);

  // Post
  $.post(url, values, function($response)
  {
    if ($response['status'])
    {
      // Success
    }
    else
    {
      // Validation error.
    }
  }, 'json');
```

My `getFormValues` functions runs some custom processing to make sure I only send the information I need so I am keen on keeping it. It is probably similar to the jQuery 'serialize' function but much simpler and with custom processing.

## The Problem

My get form values function basically does a `$('selector').val()` to get the form values. Which does not upload the file fields. It returns a fake path like `C:\fakepat\filename.png`. This of course will not work. I need to actually submit the file as part of the ajax post operation.

## The question

**Without** switching to jquery serialize (since it doesn't fully support files anyway) and **without** using any other libraries such as jquery form, How do I obtain the file from the file field and post it using ajax?

Simplified, how do I simulate the behavior of a standard file field submit with an ajax post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: look into `FormData()`, it let's you spoof file uploads in ajax.

Comment: While http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously is helpful it does not tell me how to obtain the file and add it to a post values array, only how to post all form values as a whole. I'm experimenting now but I don't think it qualifies as a duplicate.

Comment: Sure enough FormData works. I used a simplified version of the what @CharlotteDunois referenced. But this is really just a work-around. I still want to be able to obtain a file without having to wrap it in a barely supported FormData class. I have a hard time believing this was impossible to do until IE10 came out.